# Missing params[:id] in form post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes, parameters

I know I am missing something.. I don't know how to fix it.

I have a Message model which has a `body` attribute.

the controller is located under `users/messages_controller.rb`

my routes

```
  namespace :users do
    resources :messages
  end
```

which give

```
users_messages     GET    /users/messages(.:format)           users/messages#index
                   POST   /users/messages(.:format)           users/messages#create
new_users_message  GET    /users/messages/new(.:format)       users/messages#new
edit_users_message GET    /users/messages/:id/edit(.:format)  users/messages#edit
users_message      GET    /users/messages/:id(.:format)       users/messages#show
                   PUT    /users/messages/:id(.:format)       users/messages#update
                   DELETE /users/messages/:id(.:format)       users/messages#destroy
```

I created a partial which I render on users/show via

```
  <%= render :partial => 'users/messages/sendme' %>
```

_sendme.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(users_messages_path) do %>
         <%= text_area_tag "Message" %>
         <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

but when I submit a message, and it goes to the create action in messages_controller I can't pull the id of the user from which the message was sent. 
The params that I get are

```
pry(#<Users::MessagesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"Γ£ף",
 "authenticity_token"=>"IrcPBHgBp/BI...mBbOQx7gcJc5xNtAFs=",
 "Message"=>"test",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"users/messages"}
```

The URL of the users/show is `http://localhost:3000/users/24`
What do I need to add so I can get the user's ID in the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `@user` available in your form, create a `hidden_field_tag` inside it like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :id, @user.id %>
```

Then, when you submit your form, the `params[:id]` would be populated as `@user.id`.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do it without a hidden field? somehow from the user#show url?

Comment: I don't think so. The params are always the fields of the form.